# Laravel routing within a sub-folder

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to route a page located inside a sub-folder within the Views folder.

**My folder structure**

```
 -routes.php
   --Views
   ---Featured
   ----pageA.php
   ---page1.php
   ---page2.php
```

So how would I route **pageA.php** so that the url reads **mywebsite.com/featured/pageA**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('featured/pageA', function () {
    return view('Featured.pageA');
});
```

Try to avoid the use of uppercase in the URL

Comment: This is not working for me. I have other pages within the Views folder routed and working fine. Not sure what is the problem. I have the following route format setup for my other root pages. 

Route::get('some-page', function()
  {
    return View::make('some-page');
  });

Comment: Is there another alternative? or any configuration that needs to be done to have this method working? Sorry, I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: The way I told you is the correct way to declare a route so I'm thinking that maybe you have something wrong in your server's configuration